# Unicode character in Visnetwork not displaying

Tags: r, igraph, visnetwork

I tried to create a Network visualisation using R, igraph and Visnetwork library.

I'm running this on a localhost Apache server that create network on every page of a wiki (create with DokuWiki) via PHP and a specific Rscript. It basically create a network of all pages and links in a current namespace of the Wiki and displays it at the top of every pages of the namespace hilighting the node of the present page.

It works fine, the only problem is to display special font character like **a macron** in the network. For exemple I've tired **Pāṭimokkha** and it shows `P<c4><81><e1><b9><ad>imokkha` (see image)

[image]

I’ve read that it might be that the font used by visnetwork doesn’t contain these special characters. Is it possible to add a font to the library ?

Or is it something else, that is creating the problem ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this weird char `<c4><81>` are UTF-8 in hexadecimal. [see this website for testing](http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/%7Erichard/utf-8.cgi?input=c4%2081&mode=bytes)

And after testing, they appear as output of **VisSave** function when network is created.

My solution was to create a function :

```
function utf8hex ($string) {
    $string = str_replace('<c4><81>','ā',$string);
    return ($string);
}
```

And replace the char [one by one](https://suttacentral.net/mn111/en/sujato) ;-) as they appear. There is some **ut8decode** function that could be used, but more complex than my solution that works.

Cheers.